# Force g++ to generate code for unused functions

Tags: g++, code-generation, inline

By default, g++ seems to omit code for unused in-class defined methods. Example [from my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24321099):

```
struct Foo {
  void bar() {}
  void baz() {}
};

int main() {
  Foo foo;
  foo.bar();
}
```

When compiling this with `g++ -g -O0 - c main.cpp`, the resulting object file only contains references to `bar` and not to `baz`. Adding `--no-deafault-inline` to the computer flags does not help either. Any ideas how I can force g++ to generate code for `baz` as well?

**Rationale**

The test coverage tool `gcov` reports unused methods as non-executable if they are omitted from the final executable. However, to get meaningful reports I want them to be reported as executable-but-not-executed. For this, I need to find a way to achieve this without having to alter the original source code.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch I've updated my question.

Comment: This is looking like [an XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377) why is the gcov report not meaningful?  What's wrong with the current output or better with the output that you're trying to force it to make?

Answer (score 0):

A portable way to do that is to add some "reference" (in the ordinary sense, not only the C++ one, of the word) to these routines.

This could be something as simple as

```
 typedef void (Foo::*funptr_t) (void);
 extern "C" const funptr_t tabfun[] = { &Foo::bar, &Foo::baz };
```

<sup>(I'm declaring the array `tabfun` as `extern "C"` to be sure that array is emitted, even if not used)</sup>

You might try the `-fno-inline` argument to GCC. You could also customize GCC (e.g. with [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/)) to have such an array added automatically (without touching the source code), but this requires some work.